# How to Print to the Console

Tags: front-end

**Background:**

Using the settings under Edit-> Preferences->Evaluation I can redirect all the Print statments to the console.

[image: Settings dialog]

What I'd really like to do is redirect just some specific `Print` statements to the console. I know I can print to another notebook with something like:

```
PrintToNotebook[nb_, expr_] := ( 
   SelectionMove[nb, After, Cell]; 
   NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[expr]], "Print"]])
```

So perhaps this boils down to finding the "Console Handle"?

**Question:
How can I create a function (eg `PrintToConsole`) that behaves like `Print` but outputs to the console?**

**EDIT**

Turns out the trick is in `MessagesNotebook[]`. This is what I'm currently using

```
ClearAll[PrintToConsole]
$OldLine = -1;
PrintToConsole[
   expr_] := (SelectionMove[MessagesNotebook[], After, Cell];
   NotebookWrite[MessagesNotebook[], 
    Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[expr]], "Print", 
     CellLabel ->  "During evaluation of In[" <> ToString@$Line <> "]:=", 
     ShowCellLabel -> ($OldLine =!= $Line)]];
   $OldLine = $Line;);
PrintToConsole[
   expr__] := (SelectionMove[MessagesNotebook[], After, Cell];
   NotebookWrite[MessagesNotebook[], 
    Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[Row@{expr}]], "Print", 
     CellLabel -> "During evaluation of In[" <> ToString@$Line <> "]:=",
     ShowCellLabel -> ($OldLine =!= $Line)]];
   $OldLine = $Line;);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The "Messages" window or the console is just another notebook, referenced by `MessagesNotebook[]`. So to print directly to that, use:

```
Clear[PrintToConsole]
PrintToConsole[expr_] := (SetSelectedNotebook[MessagesNotebook[]]; 
    NotebookWrite[SelectedNotebook[], Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[expr]], "Print"]])
```

This will print to the console and also brings it to focus. To make the notebook visible if it already isn't, add `SetOptions[MessagesNotebook[], Visible -> True]` in the definition above. However, I don't think that either of them are good UX, because it might get annoying if you're printing something continuously, and want to work in a different notebook in the mean time.

---

To get the same behaviour as `Print` with the `During evaluation of...` lines printed, use:

```
Clear[PrintToConsole]
PrintToConsole[expr_] := (SelectionMove[MessagesNotebook[], After, Cell];
    NotebookWrite[MessagesNotebook[], 
        Cell[BoxData["During evaluation of In[" <> ToString@$Line <> "]"], "CellLabel"]];
    NotebookWrite[MessagesNotebook[], Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[expr]], "Print"]])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't find anything useful in the help under "Console". And under "Message window" there was [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/menuitem/Messages.html) unhelpful entry.

Comment: This prints to the Messages window, but it does not cause the window to become visible.  Can you add that functionality?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard See edit.

Comment: On version 7 this now prints to the evaluation Notebook if the Messages window is not already open.

Comment: Well, you just need to change `Visible -> True`, but I'm not sure if that's a good thing. Even the focus grabbing isn't good UX. The user can always choose to turn it visible or not (from the menu bar), but popping it up every time makes it annoying.

Comment: Is it possible to also get those lines `During evaluation of In[..]` such as `Print` gives when it's redirected to the console?

Comment: [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jEAWa.png) is what i mean

Comment: You're right: +1

Comment: @Ajasja See edit.

Comment: Thanks. It turns out the fonts are too small (at least on win 7). The trick was `CellLabel` (good old Ctrl+Shift+E helped here). See edit. Also why is this method much slower then print? This is not a problem for my application, just wondering:)

Comment: I don't know why it is slower, but you can control the font size for `CellLabel` in your stylesheet...