# How to monitor the progress of Map?

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, monitoring

I have a function `doSomethingComplicated[...]` that takes about 10s on average to evaluate. My list, `listOfArgs` has about 10000 elements. I'd like to monitor the progress of `Map[doSomethingComplicated, listOfArgs]` without having it ever occupying a big area of the screen.  What's best way to do that?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Using `MapIndexed`, which also gives you the index of the element in the list instead of `Map` would be very convenient. That way, you can set up a `Print` or a `PrintTemporary` cell. For example:

```
Clear[f]
f = (Pause[0.2]; PrintTemporary[First@#2]; #^2) &; (* your complicated function *)
MapIndexed[f, Range[10]]

(* 1
   2
   ...
   ...
  {1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100} *)
```

With a `PrintTemporary` cell, it prints all the output, but the cell disappears when the evaluation is complete, saving you the trouble of cleaning the mess.

You can also print directly to the messages notebook using the `PrintToConsole` function from [my answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5735/5). This keeps your current working notebook clean and you can always check in the other to see the progress.

---

Another option is to use side-effects and increment a variable, which allows you to use `Monitor`. For example:

```
Clear[g]
g = (Pause[0.2]; i = First@#2 + 1; #^2) &;
Block[{i = 1}, Monitor[MapIndexed[g, Range[10]], i]]
```

See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5980/5) by Brett Champion for the different ways in which you can create a progress bar to suit your needs.

Comment: You could write a general function to do this: MapMonitored[f_, args_List] :=
 Module[{x = 0},
  Monitor[MapIndexed[(x = #2[[1]]; f[#1]) &, args], 
   ProgressIndicator[x/Length[args]]]]

Comment: Is there any way to progress-monitor a `ParallelMap`? `MapIndexed` is not parallelizable. I don't need exact indexing, just a general sense of progress.

Answer (score 12):

With the 10.3 release and introduction of [Echo](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Echo.html) there is neat simple way:

Just wrap Echo around w/e you map:

```
Echo[f[#]] & /@ Range[5]
```

[image]

And if you want to suppress large outputs, you can do something like

```
MapIndexed[(Echo["", First[#2]]; Sin[#1]) &, Range[5]]
```

[image]

which is similar to print but pretty.

Comment: This will occupy a very big/tall area of the screen, and in a way Not Pretty^TM doesn't it?

Comment: @qazwsx i was just updating on a new function. people should use this to their convenience.