# How to see partial results during evaluation

Tags: evaluation

I am computing a long `Table[]`, but the computation of the last few elements is taking too long, and I am afraid I will never converge.
I would like to access the part of the `Table` which has been already computed and then abort the evaluation.
Is that possible and how?
Thanks.

Comment: Apparent duplicate: [(7566)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7566/121).  Related: [(8109)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8109/121), [(18519)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18519/121), [(35139)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/35139/121)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can adapt something like this

```
partial = Reap[CheckAbort[full=Table[Sow[expr]; expr, {i,1,1000}], Null]][[2,1]]
```

Comment: You could also use `TimeConstrained` instead of `CheckAbort`.