# Monitoring progress of a Series expansion

Tags: monitoring

I am currently working on a calculation which can take hours to complete. I have some do loop structure, where each step requires long time. I am able to monitor each of the steps progress. With the [Monitoring progress of long calculations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35139/monitoring-progress-of-long-calculations) post,

```
Monitor[
 Do[
   xx = xx + 1;
   , {xx, 1, 1000000}
   ];, Grid[{{Text[
     Style["Integer Factorization :", Darker[Green, 0.66]]], 
    ProgressIndicator[xx, {0, 1000000}]}, {Text[
     Style["The Progress of n : ", Darker[Green, 0.66]]], n}}, 
  Alignment -> Left, Dividers -> Center]]
```

I want a monitor for progress of a series expansion

```
Gamma[d/2 - 2] Gamma[d - 4] Gamma[
   d - 6] Gamma[d/2 - 3]/(Gamma[d - 8] Gamma[d/2 - 78])^2 /. 
 d -> 4 - 2 \[Epsilon]
```

Now when I am writing

```
Monitor[Series[%1, {\[Epsilon], 0, 12}];, 
 Grid[{{Text[Style["Integer Factorization :", Darker[Green, 0.66]]], 
    ProgressIndicator[\[Epsilon], {1, 10}]}, {Text[
     Style["The Progress of n : ", Darker[Green, 0.66]]], n}}, 
  Alignment -> Left, Dividers -> Center]]
```

But it is not showing the progress bar.How to do this in mathematica?

Comment: The "ProgressIndicator" needs an increasing  variable not a undefined symbol.

Comment: What is %1 in this example?