# Print to console bis

Tags: printing

In the answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5734/how-to-print-to-the-console), one explains how to use a function

> PrintToConsole[...]

to print output to the console. My question: can you make a global definition that will automatically print *all* output to the message box, without having to wrap PrintToConsole around a specific line of code?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
$PrePrint = PrintToConsole
```

which will have this effect. You can read more about this and other alternatives [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheMainLoop.html).