# What ordering function does Sort use to sort the open notebooks list?

Tags: notebooks

After bustling about `Sort @ Notebooks[]` for a while, I have surmised that notebook are listed in decreasing order this way:

- `Message`
- saved notebook by file date
- unsaved notebook by creation date

Please, con you confirm or deny ?

By the way, this could be exploited to write on Message notebook in  a simply manner:

```
writeOnMessageNotebook[arg_]:=
NotebookWrite[First @ Sort @ Notebooks[], arg]
```

I think that `WindowTitle` isn't involed in this topic because

```
(WindowTitle /. Options[#]) & /@ Notebooks[]
```

returns

```
{WindowTitle, "Sort - Wolfram Mathematica", WindowTitle}
```

even with saved notebooks opened.

Comment: Your proposed ordering seems to hold on my system too. I'll add that notebooks opened as documentation pages appear *last* in that ordering. By the way, you can write to the Messages window by referring to it with the undocumented `MessagesNotebook[]` (see [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5735/27951) and the comments under it for a discussion of why that may not be desirable).

Comment: Thank for the reply ! I have just checked that `MessagesNotebook[]` works on both ver. 7.0.0 and 8.0.1. I'm going to test on ver. 10.